# VSE: Select all the strips of a given track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to automatically select all the strips of a given track, for example of the track of the selected strip (a kind of equivalent of <kbd>L</kbd> in the *Dope Sheet*)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select a strip on the channel you want, then use *Select* > *Channel* > ***Both sides***.

`bpy.ops.sequencer.select_side(side='BOTH')`

Comment: oh of course thanks a lot